# Microsoft Office PowerPoint Add-ins: Can Javascript shared runtime support a content add-in?

Tags: office-js

The documentation explains how to use a shared runtime:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime

However, the pages only address task pane add-ins, not content add-ins. I would like to know if the shared runtime support content add-ins, if so, the multiple content add-ins in some slides of a PowerPoint can share a single js library ,then reduce js resource download and loading time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one open window at a time with a shared runtime, so you can't have multiple content add-ins sharing the same runtime at this time. But it is an interesting idea. Please suggest it at [Office developer suggestion box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).